# Concatenating multiple (any number) spark DataFrame columns into one "|" deliminated string

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, user-defined-functions

I have a DataFrame and a list of columns as strings, and I need to add on a column to the original dataframe that is a `|` separated list of the values, where `null` gets turned into the string `"null"`

This is the code I currently have:

```
def mergeColumns(cols: Array[String], df: DataFrame, newName: String): DataFrame = {
  val dfColumns = cols.map( columnName => df(columnName) )
  df.withColumn(newName, concatenate(array(dfColumns: _*), lit("|")))
}
val concatenate: UserDefinedFunction = udf( (columns: Seq[Any], separator: String) => {
  columns.map({
    case null => "null"
    case default => default.toString
  }).mkString(separator)
})
```

And that code works, but only if all the provided columns are of the same type, and my current plan is to try to convert them all to String type. So I have two questions:
1) Is there a better way to do this in general?
2) If not, how can I convert all the `dfColumns` columns into strings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this using `mkString` on the `Row` class :

```
val df =Seq(
  ("a", "b",Option.empty[String])
).toDF("Col1","Col2","Col3")

val makeString = udf((r : Row) => r.mkString("|"))

df.withColumn("newCol",makeString(struct("*")))
  .show()
```

gives

```
+----+----+----+--------+
|Col1|Col2|Col3|  newCol|
+----+----+----+--------+
|   a|   b|null|a|b|null|
+----+----+----+--------+
```

Comment: What if I want only a subset of those columns, say `Col2` and `Col3`. I still want the original columns with it, so the schema would still be `Col1, Col2, Col3, newCol`

Comment: I figured out the answer to my question, just use `struct(columns: _*)` in place of `struct("*")` where `columns` is `dfColumns` from the original post.

Answer (score 0):

Try with **`fill null values`** and **`concat_ws`** functions.

***EX:***

```
val df =Seq(
           ("a", "b",Option.empty[String]))
           .toDF("Col1","Col2","Col3")
df.na.fill("null")
     .withColumn("cn_ws",concat_ws("|", array("*")))
     .show(false)
```

Result:

```
+----+----+----+--------+
|Col1|Col2|Col3|cn_ws   |
+----+----+----+--------+
|a   |b   |null|a|b|null|
+----+----+----+--------+
```

***UPDATE:***

Cast all columns to **`"string"`**

```
df.na.fill("null")
     .withColumn("cn_ws", 
       concat_ws("|", array(df.columns.map(c => col(c).cast(StringType)): _*)))
     .show(false)
```

Comment: According to the docs: `Concatenates multiple input string columns together into a single string column, using the given separator.` Is there a way to ensure all columns will be string columns?

Comment: @JaredDuPont, Please check my updated answer..! :-)